# Pass a iteration in for() loop if timeout occurs

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I have a `method`, that uses `try/catch` to `request` with `requests` some urls.

If a timeout occurs (in the `except`), how can I modify my code to just continue to the next `req` in the for loop?

I've tried doing some homework with `pass`, `break` statements in python, but neither seemed to be a good fit.

```
try:
    request = requests.get(the_path, timeout=1.0, verify=False)
        for req in request:
            if inst.val in req:
                print req
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print 'We timed out'
    <somehow continue to next iteration of req>
```

Can someone enlighten me on how to do this? Thank you

Comment: If the request timed out, then there shouldn't be any more iterations to process. Did you mean to iterate over a list of paths?

Comment: Are you talking about the `for req in request` loop? You are iterating over the content body there; if the request timed out *there is no request body*.

Comment: In any case, if you have hit the exception handler, the request has failed. You can no longer iterate to the next chunk of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `continue` statement.

Comment: Logically, this seemed right, but after reading this article: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm. It states "The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning of the while loop" - but, I don't want to continue from the beginning of the loop. I want to continue from the request that failed

Comment: @CodeTalk What?! `continue` will not go to the beginning of the loop. Never!

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - haha, I'm just going off what the link above shows

Comment: Thank you both. Yet a tad more newbie-ness gone.

Comment: @CodeTalk - I mean `continue` will not start iterating from the beginning. It will go to the first line of the loop body to work with the next element served by iterator.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - thank you so much for explaining. (Noted shouldn't be following outdated sites anymore :) )